# namespacing in PHP does everything inside the namespace get carried across when using it?

Tags: php, namespaces

If I have the following code:

```
namespace System
{
    namespace Models
    {

        $modelsFolder = "Models";
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/Site.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/Session.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/Form.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/Recaptcha.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/AppCred.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/User.php" );
        require_once( "../$modelsFolder/Database.php" );
    }

    namespace Controllers
    {
        namespace System\Models;
        $db = new Database();       
    }
}
```

If in my controller files I then always state:

```
namespace System\Controllers;

$db->Query(); // will this work because it has been declared in the namespace Controllers?
```

Will the instance of $db be brought across into this file? or do I need to declare my $db outside of the namespace and include it before the controller file is included?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not affected by namespaces to begin with. What you're creating there is a regular global variable whose scope is not restricted by anything. Scope != namespace.

Comment: That's excellent news then! :D Let me just run some code and see if it works how I expect then i'll tick as answer ^_^